# Python function requires path but I have an image stored in memory

Tags: python, file, pythonista

I have a python function (using the Pythonista app) to show an image in the console. I have the image saved in a BytesIO object but the function requires a file path.

Is there any way to give it a path to the bytesIO or somehow give it the image without needing to save it as a file?

The specific function is console.show_image(image_path)

Comment: Did you read the documentation?  Pythonista [apparently](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/) only runs on IOS, so I can't access it.  It says it has full documentation within the app.

Comment: It’s not in the documentation. My question is not specifically about pythonista, I just added this for additional information.

Comment: Have you tried passing your BytesIO ?

Comment: you could write it to a [NamedTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile)

Comment: or you can use `Image.show()` according to this [post](https://forum.omz-software.com/topic/1705/displaying-an-image/3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general answer is that if the function you call expects a filesystem path and cannot handle a file-like object instead then your only solution is to write your data to a file (and ask the function's author to add support for file-like object, or if it's OSS implement it by yourself and send a merge request).